# How to dodge the top bar in CSS

Tags: css, mobile

I want to make a full page menu in CSS with block elements. I don't want that page to scroll.

Right now I'm using VH to make each of my 3 rows 33vw, but the top bar seems to still count. So the page can still scroll.

I dont want the page to scroll, so how do I, in CSS, have 33% height counting out that top bar.

By top bar I'm saying the bar where your tabs and adress are.

Also, can the solution work with iOS too?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want the rows to be 33vh... you want them to each be 1/3rd of the height left over from the page height minus the top bar? And do you know the height of the top bar or is that variable?

Comment: oh, is the bar part of your layout or are you saying that's the phone's menu? It would help us quite a bit if you shared the code that isn't working currently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer if I understand your issue:

overflow-x: hidden;
would hide x-axis scroll

overflow-y: hidden;
would hide y-axis scroll

overflow: hidden;
would remove both scrollbars

```
<style type="text/css">
    .main__container {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100px;
        /*Note - this is key as it will stop scroll x and y*/
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .main__container .nav__container {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main__container .content__list {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .main__container .content__list .content__row {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 90px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<main class="main__container">
    <nav class="nav__container">
        {{--Nav HTML here --}}
    </nav>
    <ul class="content__list">
        <li class="content__row one"></li>
        <li class="content__row two"></li>
        <li class="content__row there"></li>
    </ul>
</main>
```